# Extract specific folder from tarball into specific folder

Tags: command-line, tar

I created a tarball on Ubuntu 14.04 with:

```bsh
cd /tmp
tar -cfvz archive.tar.gz /folder
```

Now I want to extract a specific folder in the tarball (which inside the tarball lies in `/tmp`) into a specific folder:

```bsh
cd /tmp
tar -xfvz archive.tar.gz folder/in/archive -C /tmp/archive
```

The result should be a new folder in `/tmp` called `archive`. Is this correct? Especially the missing slash (relative path) for the folder to be extracted and the absolute path with the leading slash for the folder to create?

Comment: tar -cfvz archive.tar.gz /folder this will archie a folder under the root directory (/) not from /tmp one... is this what you meant? the file archive.tar.gz will be in /tmp. For the second part you must switch the -C and the foder definition tar -xfvz archive.tar.gz -C /tmp/archive folder/in/archive

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Tl;dr

Since you are in `/tmp` already, you can just discard the `-C` option (since by default `tar` will extract files in the current working directory) and just add `--strip-components=2`:

```bsh
tar --strip-components=2 -xfvz archive.tar.gz folder/in/archive
```

---

GNU `tar` by default stores relative paths.

Whether an archive uses relative paths can be checked by running `tar -tf archive | head -n 1`, which will print the path of the first file in the archive; if that file's path is a relative path, all the files in the archive use relative paths:

```bsh
% tar -tf bash-4.3.tar.gz | head -n 1
bash-4.3/
```

To extract a single file / folder from an archive that uses relative paths without its ancestors into a relative path you'll need two options: `-C` and `--strip-components=N`: in the example below the archive `bash-4.3.tar.gz` uses relative paths and contains a file `bash-4.3/doc/bash.html` which is extracted into a relative path `path` (`-C` specifies the directory in which to extract the files, `--strip-components=2` specifies that the parent and the parent of the parent of the extracted files should be ignored, so in this case only `bash.html` will be extracted into the target directory):

```
% tree
.
├── bash-4.3.tar.gz
└── path

1 directory, 1 file
% tar -tf bash-4.3.tar.gz | grep -F 'bash.html'
bash-4.3/doc/bash.html
% tar -C path --strip-components=2 -zxf bash-4.3.tar.gz bash-4.3/doc/bash.html
% tree
.
├── bash-4.3.tar.gz
└── path
    └── bash.html

1 directory, 2 files
```

So, back to your command, since you are in `/tmp` already, you can just discard the `-C` option (since by default `tar` will extract files in the current working directory) and just add `--strip-components=2`:

```bsh
tar --strip-components=2 -xfvz archive.tar.gz folder/in/archive
```

Comment: `tar --strip-components=3 -zxvf iot_db.tar.gz` worked for me, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

`tar` stores relative paths

If you need to extract a particular folder, have a look at what's in the tar file:

```
tar -tvf archive.tar.gz
```

And note the exact filename. 
    `tar -xvf foo.tar folder/in/archive`
  # Note: no leading slash